# Angular2 - give focus to button into a div hidden

Tags: angular, accessibility

I work on an Angular project where I try to implement a11y for each button and link which are tabbable.

When I press Enter on the menu button, a div appears with the menu links as well as a close button. This div exists in the DOM, but its visibility is hidden.

A Material animation is called to make this div appear. **I would like to give focus to the close button inside this div** using autofocus and tabindex but the button doesn't get focused.

**App**

```
<div class="panel">
    <button (click)="toggleMenu()">Open</button>
</div>
```

**Menu**

```
<div class="menu">
    <button
        class="close animation-close-in"
        (click)="toggleMenu()"
        [attr.autofocus]="isMenuOpen() ? 'autofocus': null"
        [attr.tabindex]="isMenuOpen() ? '0': null"
      >
      Close
    </button>
    <!-- Links list -->
</div>
```

**Service**

```
open = false;

public toggleMenu(): void {
    this.open = !this.open;
    if (this.open) {
      this.scrollService.disableScroll();
    } else {
      this.scrollService.enableScroll();
    }
}

public isMenuOpen(): boolean {
    return this.isOpen();
}

public isOpen(): boolean {
    return this.open;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `autofocus` attribute is used when the page loads:

> The autofocus content attribute allows the author to indicate that a control is to be focused as soon as the page is loaded, allowing the user to just start typing without having to manually focus the main control.

you have to manually focus the button using the `focus()` function inside your toggleMenu() function. For instance:

```
document.getElementById("mybutton").focus();
```

where mybutton is the id of the button element.

Note that you do not have to set the `tabindex` attribute on the element.